# How can I share a reducer 's initial state with another reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, react-redux-form

I have an rootReducers who's initial state is some user's data stored in local storage when user is authenticated (or empty object when user is not).

In my app I have a form managed by [react-redux-form](https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs.html) that updates the user's info.

The problem I have is I would like to update the state of the rootReducer so I don't have to manage 2 different sets of user data. For that I though I could share the rootReducer's state with the form's reducer. I'm not sure what's the best way to acheive this, ps: I'm a redux newbie.

This is how I set up my rootReducer:

```
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const initialUserState = user ? { loggedIn: true, user } : {};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authentication,
  registration,
  profileUpdate,
  alert,
  ...createForms({
    userLogin    : {},
    userRegister : {},
    userProfile   : initialUserState,
  }), 
});
```

where I would like for initialUserState to be share between the userProfile react-redux-form reducer and the authentication reducer which holds the initial user data after authentication and that is saved on localStorage.

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably looking for `connect()`, `mapStateToProps()` and `mapDispatchToProps()` from `redux`

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to connect() my form since react-redux-form takes care of it already, the thing is the react-redux-form expects an initial state, I would like for that state to be the one I create at the rootReducer's level, not sure how

Comment: It sounds like you need to follow the example that shows you how to pre-populate a form by loading data into it. You would load the intitialRoot data into the form on page load with an action. https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/examples/initializefromstate/

Comment: thanks @SpencerBigum but I'm not using redux-form I'm using [react-redux-form](https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs.html) my issue is not so much how to prepopulate the form than using the right state so that I only have 1 state to manage, that state is held by my authentication reducer that I'd like to share with my form.

Comment: I suggest you use from redux-form.

Comment: @drfunkensztajn - The form needs to be initialized from your main state somehow - Im not sure if react-redux-form does this, but thats the only way you don't duplicate state. Initialize the form, changes get made temporarily using the form, then the changes get saved and updated to state after submitting. Thats the flow for using forms I think. Sorry about linking the wrong library - I would consider checking it out though.

Comment: Thanks @SpencerBigum I'll look into redux-form, I chose the other one because it's supposed to have less "magic" under the hood

Comment: @SpencerBigum I've actually followed your hints and dispatched a second action to update the authentication state with after submitting, now I'm not sure where to update the localstorage, I could easily do it in the reducer but that would be bad practice I understand?

Comment: I've done a bit of reading and what I think I need is to have a callback in the action that the authentication's reducer uses so I can then write the new data to localstorage, is thunk a good candidate to do that ?

Comment: NICE man! without looking at your code I can't 100% say you need a callback on the action. I think as long as your first action submitting data from the form is asynchronous, you can just dispatch a second action after it completes to save the data to localStorage using async/await and Thunk for all these actions/reducers - like you suggested. This way if you need to save localData somewhere else you already have the action and code written for it just to keep things as clean, organized, and separate as possible. Hopefully that helps. Cheers